# How to invoke method of QML object from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have following QML code:

```
Rectangle {
id: mainRect
...
    Rectangle{
    id: listRect
    ...
       ListModel {
          id: idModel
          ... some stuff added
       }
    }
}
```

And I want to clear idModel, using [clear](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-listmodel.html#clear-method) method of ListModel.
Stuff like this (inside QML) works perfectly:

```
 idModel.clear()
```

But I want to achieve same in C++.
Tried following:

```
  QQuickView view;
  view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
  QQuickItem* item = view.rootObject();
  QObject* model = item->findChild<QObject*>("mainRect")->findChild<QObject*>("listRect")->findChild<QObject*>("idModel");
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(model,"clear");
```

also tried to search model as

```
 QObject* model = item->findChild<QObject*>("idModel");
 QObject* model = item->findChild<QObject*>("listRect")->findChild<QObject*>("idModel");
```

But this stuff above not working... I can't even understand - if nothing is found by findChild method in C++, or InvokeMethod is not working.

Could anyone explain this to me?
Using QT5.4 \ QtQuick 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `findChild()` you should set `objectName` to your qml item.

```
Rectangle {
id: mainRect
...
    Rectangle{
    id: listRect
    ...
       ListModel {
          id: idModel
          objectName: "idModel"
          ... some stuff added
       }
    }
}
```

Then, you can get pointer to your ListModel

```
QObject* model = item->findChild<QObject*>("idModel");
```

To invoke method, you should use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(model,"clear");
```